# right code with json_decode function

Tags: php, json

I have an error while i try to activate a wp plugin:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['   at this line :

```
$site_name = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true)["site_name"];
```

---

This can be fixed by setting PHP to >= 5.4 OR with the post below.

Comment: You can only use that syntax in PHP >= 5.4.  Otherwise, you need to save the result from `json_decode` into its own variable and then use that to get the `site_name`.

Comment: I know error messages can be a bit daunting but come on! It's written right there in plain english...

Comment: Emissary : before i post the question here,i tired to fix it myself,and then i searched in php manual, and i didn't find any json_decode function written like this..I never studied about JSON in my life,how i can guess how it's should be written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use that syntax in PHP >= 5.4.  Otherwise, you need to save the result from `json_decode` into its own variable and then use that to get the `site_name`.

```
$JSONdata = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
$site_name = $JSONdata["site_name"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need PHP 5.4 for this to work. If you are running older PHP version (and assuming this plugin does not need PHP5.4 for other things) then replace this code with:

```
$tmp = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
$site_name = $tmp["site_name"];
```